# How to prove in Coq ~~(P \/ ~P)

Tags: logic, coq

I want to prove `~~(P \/ ~P)` in Coq, which sounds somehow trivial... However I do not know where to go since there is not any single hypothesis.
I have written the following code which is not working, since it is giving the following exception `[ltac_use_default] expected after [tactic] (in [tactic_command]).`

```
Parameter P: Prop.

Section r20.
Lemma regra1: ~~(P \/ ~P).
Proof.
  intro.
   - cut P.
   - cut ~P
Qed.
End r20.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is little tricky one. Here is one way to prove it.

```
Parameter P : Prop.

Section r20.
Lemma regra1: ~~(P \/ ~P).
Proof.
  unfold not. intros H1.
  apply H1. right.
  intros H2.
  apply H1. left.
  exact H2.
Qed.
End r20.
```

Comment: Thank you, Divyanshu Ranjan... Can you explain me why do we need to use exact H2 in the last line... I have tried here with assumption and it seems to work as well

Comment: Either assumption or exact H2 should work. exact H2 means goal is same as hypothesis H2, assumption does same thing

Comment: The difference between exact and assumption is that for exact the hypothesis needs just be be unifiable with the goal. For assumption the hypothesis has to match the goal syntactically. The advantage of assumption is that it automatically searches for a matching hypothesis. So assumption is more used for trivial cases, exact more for not so obviously matching cases.